# Opening RTSP stream with OpenCV (Python) from outside local network

Tags: opencv, flash, video, video-streaming, rtsp

I purchased an IP camera, and I was planning to use its video stream as input for OpenCV (with Python) to run some machine learning algorithms on the video frames.

I opened port 554 for RTSP on my router, and now I'm trying to access the stream by using (11 identifies the main video stream):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://user_name:password@camera_IP:554/11")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ...
```

It works without any problems from within the local network, but not from outside...in this case, frame is returned as a 'NoneType' object.
In the camera settings, ports 80 and 1935 are indicated for HTTP and RTMP, respectively. I tried to use them as well, but without any success.

If I simply open the camera IP in a browser, I get to the configuration page, and there I have the possibility to watch the live stream. It's embedded in a Flash object, and I'm trying to figure out if I can extract the video stream URL from it.
I viewed the page source, and there seems to be a reference to the source of the stream:

```
flashvars="&amp;src=rtmp://camera_IP:1935/flash/11:YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=&amp
```

but I wasn't able to use it to fetch the stream in OpenCV.

Any suggestion, or should I just go for another camera?